# Русский язык в бинарном файле C++

Tags: windows, файлы, c++

Делаю мини БД, и возникла такая проблема. БД работает через структуры, т.е. идёт добавление записей в файл.

```
void write(FILE *file, int readCount, Student *notes, int writeCount) {
    fseek(file, readCount * sizeof(Student), SEEK_SET);
    for(int z = 0; z < writeCount; z++){
        fwrite(&notes[z], sizeof(Student), 1, file);
    }
}
```

И считывание:

```
Student *read(FILE *file, long int a) {
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    Student *readfile = new Student[a];
    fread(readfile, sizeof(Student), a, file);
    return readfile;
}
```

Структура:

```
struct Student {

    char firstname[30];
    char secondname[30];
    char lastname[30];
    int age;
    int course;
    int group;
};
```

ОС: Windows

Проблема в том, что когда я хочу добавить запись на русском языке, она добавляется, но при считывании выводит не ту кодировку. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Покажите определение структуры Student.

Comment: А как Вы наблюдаете (конкретно), что кодировка не та?

Кстати, ОС какая (винда, наверное)?

Comment: @avp, чтением структуры из файла

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что структура, которую вы печатаете перед fwrite и она же, но после fread выглядят **на том же самом** терминале по разному?

--

Кстати, называть свои функции `read` и `write` нехорошо. Обязательно рано или поздно налетите на ошибки линкера.

Comment: хм, вы записывали в какой кодировке? а читаете в какой? и в какой показывает ваш редактор?

Comment: Я не знаю, в какой кодировке записывается структура. Использую fopen с флагом a+b. Читаю с тем же флагом.

@avp, да, именно так.

Я могу скинуть скомпилированную программу, и вы наглядно всё сможете увидеть.

Comment: > не знаю, в какой кодировке записывается структура

Это уже катастрофа. Нет понятия "русский текст", есть лишь понятия "текст в кодировке CP1251", "текст в кодировке KOI8-R", "текст в кодировке CP866", "текст в кодировке UTF-8" и т.д.

Вы _не можете_ записать русский текст в непонятно какой кодировке, а потом работать с ним.

Comment: "Не читается русский текст" означает лишь "редактор/IDE/терминал работают не в той кодировке, в которой я выдаю им данные".

Comment: Не нужна нам "скомпилированная программа". Нужно определение структуры. Но попробую телепатию напрячь. Поля, для которых слетает кодировка, объявлены как `char * field;` или `std::string field;`. При таком подходе, вышеуказанный способ сохранения записей не будет работать нормально. И слетевшая кодировка - это еще небольшая проблема.

Показывайте определение структуры `Student`. Скомпилировать код уж как то смогу и я, и другие участники.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, если условия позволяют, стоит использовать файловые потоки. Если не заработает автоматически, то можно принудительно задавать кодировки.